# HAProxy HTTP Response "Other"

Tags: http, haproxy, http-status-code

The [HAProxy documentation](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#9.1) lists the possibility of returning non-conforming HTTP status codes:

> `hrsp_other` [.FBS]: http responses with other codes (protocol error)

Are these simply error codes generated by a non-HTTP application whose requests are also being proxied by HAProxy? Or something else altogether?

I have combed through the HAProxy documentation and could find no other mention of these otherwise invalid http responses.